# The name 'SharePointContextProvider' does not exist in the current context

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012, provider-hosted-app

I have a Basic Provider Hosted App (which is an on premise hosted app). It has been integrated with SP2013 and hello world Page is working fine. But when I wanted to develop the actual part, I have to use SharePointContextProvider, but the compiler is throwing an error.

> The name 'SharePointContextProvider' does not exist in the current context.

Here is my actual code.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User spUser = null;

        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                ViewBag.UserName = spUser.Title;
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

In View I want to use the User Name.
I am using VS 2012 and SP 2013.

Answer (score 5):

Has your method the following attributes? [SharePointContextFilter]

But more important. Are in your MVC application included the SharePoint context file?
SharePointContext.cs and TokenHelper.cs

You can find them here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/

Comment: Sorry, the SharepointContext.cs is not included in the project. Do I need to manually include them?.

Comment: Yes, add both them and than retry.

Comment: Is there any reason why SharePointContext.cs & TokenHelper.cs are not getting included in solution. Because I remember when i created first Provider Hosted App before 18 months it use to get added in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by installing **Window Foundation Identity**.

You can download this from [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17331) and download only x64 msu.